# "Enable Java Script Error" in Request.get for a php generated page with no javascript

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, python-requests

I have a PHP generated page that outputs a simple 4 lines of text that looks like this:

```
US_PIN: 7312

UK_PIN: 2221

NL_PIN: 8903

CA_PIN: 2850
```

But when I try to access this URL from python requests.get with this code:

```py
urldata = requests.get("http://dsthedev.gigfa.com/pincatch.php")
```

It gives me this output:

```html
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("0397ff67e9b4abec3a5fe06a3a88675e");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://dsthedev.gigfa.com/pincatch.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

In Chrome inspect I found a cookie in request header and with this new code it works on my current network but as soon as I change my connection or try to run this on another PC it stops working.

```py
urldata = requests.get("http://dsthedev.gigfa.com/pincatch.php",cookies={'__test':'9034b43ea95baa314f2dd94fa3ac4455'})
```

My web host which runs the PHP is a free sub-domain with cPanel. (I'm not familiar so much with web hosting).

I tried another URLs with .txt in my sub-domain and it raises the same JavaScript error.

Comment: Do you have some sort of htaccess redirect or block? I get the text with a graphic browser, but when I try with wget, curl, or lynx, I get 403: Forbidden

Comment: I didn't change anything in my web host but add the PHP code. There is a htaccess file in root folder by default. What can i do?

Comment: Contact your web host, they may have some sort of injection happening that you can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found no solution so far I decided to use chrome webdrive, but since it's very slow compared to the python requests lib I decided to use it as a function to grab the cookie and save it then import the cookie into requests.get(). If it fails (If connection changes and so the cookie) it calls the function again to get the new cookie and save it.

It works and it's very time efficient and since the cookie for the website isn't something for login I don't think saving it in a file suggests any security issue.